# Filtering the scraped data using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have succesfully scraped a data from websites page. But it contain both the HTML tags aswell as plain text. How can i filter the unwanted data (tags,scripts,some text which is not required,etc) from this scraped data. Atleast suggest some approach for doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)  to parse the html and remove any unwanted takes.

> [How to use HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 1):

You can start by taking a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). This should allow you to remove any HTML.

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).